# "Initializing geometry from JSON input requires GDAL" Error

Tags: json, django, leaflet, geojson, gdal

I'm doing a Django project and I want to save polygons that represent areas of interest in a map. I am trying to use django-leaflet and django-geojson. The model for the shapes is:

```
#models.py
...
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gismodels
...
class MushroomShape(gismodels.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    geom = gismodels.PolygonField()
    objects = gismodels.GeoManager()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I'm trying to create the polygon shapes in the admin, using a leaflet widget, to be added to the Database:

```
#admin.py
...
from leaflet.admin import LeafletGeoAdmin
from .models import MushroomShape
...
admin.site.register(MushroomShape, LeafletGeoAdmin)
```

Running the server in my computer, when I draw a polygon in the admin form and try to submit it:
The client side reports "Invalid geometry value." and the server side reports:

> Error creating geometry from value
>   '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.58575439453125,41.83375828633243],[-87.58575439453125,42.002366213375524],[-86.74942016601562,42.002366213375524],[-86.74942016601562,41.83375828633243],[-87.58575439453125,41.83375828633243]]]}'
>   (Initializing geometry from JSON input requires GDAL.)

A little push to help understand where I have to look, to solve this error, would be really awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if this is bad etiquette (posting an answer to my question instead of deleting), but I've found my answer in the official Django page for geo libraries:

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/

I didn't know GDAL is necessary for some geojson features that I tried to use to work. I've followed their instructions and installed it with

```
sudo apt-get install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin
```

and my error is gone.